# Why does f77 -f fail and what should it do?

Tags: makefile, fortran

I am trying to run some old Fortran code of my project team in ubuntu 16.04. I have not done any modifications to the existing code.
All I have done is installed gfortran, opened a terminal, and went to the file location using "cd" command. Here I have many files, but just consider this three, a script file `compile.sh`, and two makefiles `counter.make` and `remail.make`.
In `compile.sh`

```
make -f counter.make
make -f remail.make
```

In `counter.make`

```
SOURCE_APPLI=../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/
SOURCES_f77 = $(SOURCE_APPLI)table.f
TARGET = unst.e
OBJECTS =  $(SOURCES_f77:.f=.o)
COMPILE = f77 -f
.f90.o :
    $(COMPILE1) -o $*.o -c $*.f90
.f.o :
    $(COMPILE) -o $*.o -c $*.f
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE)  $(OBJECTS) -o $@
del :
    $(DELETE) $(OBJECTS)
```

In `remail.make`

```
SOURCE_APPLI= ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/
$(SOURCE_APPLI)grcom.f
TARGET = remail.e
OBJECTS =  $(SOURCES_f77:.f=.o)
COMPILE = f90
.f90.o :
    $(COMPILE) -o $*.o -c $*.f90
.f.o :  
    $(COMPILE) -o $*.o -c $*.f
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE)  $(OBJECTS) -o $@
del :
    $(DELETE) $(OBJECTS)
```

When I run `compile.sh`, I got an error as shown below

```
f77: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-f’
counter.make:29: recipe for target 'unst.e' failed
make: *** [unst.e] Error 1
make: 'remail.e' is up to date.
```

So my question is what is the difference with and without using `-f` option in the `f77` command line?

Comment: The `f77: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-f’` comes from `f77`, not from `make`.

Comment: Confusingly there are two -f options, `make -f` and `f77 -f`. The latter is almost certainly wrong as on ubuntu f77 maps to gfortran which doesn't have a -f option. The question about the former can be answered simply by reading `man make`

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for your reply. I have gfortran (GNU Fortran 95 compiler) and gfortran-5 (GNU Fortran compiler) in my system. Is there any specific compiler for f77?

Comment: Type `type f77`, it probably points to `gfortran`, IIRC they do it this way on Ubuntu.

Comment: @VladimirF I typed `type f77` in the terminal window and got an output as `f77 is /usr/bin/f77`. Is this correct ?

Comment: @IanBush Thanks for you reply. Are you suggesting to remove `-f` from `f77 -f` section of `counter.make` file. Also can you please explain `man make`?

Comment: Type `man make` at the command line and read what it says for the `-f` flag. `man` is short for manual.

Comment: You can probably remove `-f`, but not knowing what it is supposed to do I can't say for certain. You will have to find out what the original f77 compiler was that was used, and tell us if you want more information, but as long as the code is well written ultimately it shouldn't matter.

Comment: If you put the `-f` there, why? If somebody else put it there, ask them.

Comment: @IanBush typing `man make` give `-f file`. I compiled without `-f` and got this `f77  ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/table.o -o unst.e 
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/racal.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your reply. This code was like 10+ years old and the authors are not here anymore. I am trying to understand this code for my work. One more question, is the  `unst.e` and `remail.e` in the make files `counter.make` and `remail.make` are the executables?

Comment: Looks like it is, though that's a weird convention.

Comment: The [manual page I found online](https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/f77/) suggests that you want to move `$*.f` to immediately after `$(COMPILE)`, or restructure the recipe so that the `-f` flag is not part of `$(COMPILE)` itself. (Putting just the compiler and _one_ option in a variable seems like just wacky obfuscation anyway.)

Comment: @tripleee Wierd indeed. You were asking about the `-f` flag. Do you meant in `compiler.sh` file or `counter.make` file ?

Comment: I think in `counter.make` but this is a twiisty maze of nested dependencies. Like already pointed out elsewhere, `make -f` is not the problem here, and the correct syntax when you want to use a Makefile with a different name than the default.

Comment: The error message in an earlier comment sounds like `../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/table.o` was compiled on a different system than the one you are on now, and is unrelated to anything in your question. Try recompiling the file in the other directory and then come back and try again. (Probably move the existing file to the side so you can put it back if you find out you wanted to keep it after all.)

Comment: @tripleee, Yes its very confusing. Can you please tell me what is the meaning of line 9, 10 and 11 in the `counter.make` file?

Comment: That's a weird question, the 9th line is the body of the `.f.o:` rule and then if you don't understand that, why are you not also asking about lines 7 and 8? Lines 10-11 define how to compile `$(TARGET)`.

Comment: @tripleee, sorry for that question. In your earlier comment, you mentioned about moving `$*.f` immediately after `$(COMPILE)` or restructuring the recipe. So what I meant to ask you is if I put `$*.f` as per the suggestion in the document, how its meaning is different from the original version?

Comment: I misread the manual page I found, it says `-f` specifies floating point emulation and does not take an argument, so probably don't try reordering the arguments. The `-f` option only seemed to make sense for really old hardware anyway; perhaps investigate whether or not it is useful at all in your scenario.

Comment: @tripleee, `remail.make` file compiles using f90 and produce an output `make: 'remail.e' is up to date.` and `counter.make` file compiles using f77. So I changed the compile option to `f90` in `counter.make` file which produce an output `f90 ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/table.o -o unst.e ` `make: f90: command not found` `counter.make:: recipe for target 'unst.e' failed` `make: *** [unst.e] Error 127`

Comment: Why did you do that though?

Comment: @tripleee, just thought to try. Do you have any idea why two different make files use two different Fortran options such as f77 and f90 ?

Comment: I would assume that the input source code uses different features of the language which require different compilers, but I basically know nothing about Fortran. The fact that the Makefile author created different recipes within the same Makefile strongly suggests that they had a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `f77` manual page at https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/f77/ says

> `-f`     Use a floating point interpreter
> (for PDP11's that lack 11/70-style floating point).

If you are not on a PDP-11, it appears that this option would perhaps not be useful at all in the first place.

Probably still review the *local* documentation, ideally for the system where this set of `Makefile`s was once created.

[GNU Fortran 77](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-f77/) appears to use this option to specify various language options, but then it would not be useful on its own (it takes arguments like `-fdollar-ok` to enable something called "dollar ok", for example. See the linked manual for an extensive list of these options and their meaning).